# Modifying a known titlesec macro for chapters for variable length rule

Tags: macros, formatting, titlesec

I am currently typesetting a `book` style document, and I used `titlesec` package to modify the chapter titleformat using the following lines of code:-

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=count]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
{\iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
    \bibopenbracket}%
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
{\supercitedelim}
{\bibclosebracket}
\let\cite=\supercite
\usepackage{
mathtools,amsthm,
siunitx, 
enumerate, 
kantlipsum, 
froufrou, 
bm, 
nicefrac, 
cancel, 
tabularx,booktabs, 
hf-tikz, 
esvect,
pdfpages
}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[bottom, flushmargin, hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
format={hang},
font={small},
labelsep={colon},
textfont={it},
labelfont={bf}
}
\usepackage[
bookmarksnumbered=true,
linktoc=page,
colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=Green,
bookmarksopenlevel=2
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}     
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, headsep=30pt]{geometry}                 
\usepackage{setspace, parskip}                   
\setstretch{1.25}          
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont}{\rule{.05\textwidth}{0.5pt}
    \raisebox{-3pt}{\footnotesize
        \enspace\!\!\!\! CHAPTER \thechapter\!\enspace}\hrulefill\vspace*{-12pt}}
{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\itshape\filcenter}[\vspace*{6pt}\hrule height 0.5pt]
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{36pt}         
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\S\,\thesection}{8pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}{\S\,\thesubsection}
{8pt}{\Large\normalfont\itshape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\pageoffset}
\setlength{\pageoffset}{10mm}% use whatever you like
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\pageoffset}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Ch\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\S\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{fancy2}{
    \fancyhead[LE]{\makebox[\pageoffset][l]{\bfseries\thepage}\bfseries\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark\makebox[\pageoffset][r]{\bfseries\thepage}}  
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\thepage}
}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \begingroup
    \mbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
%       \textcolor{white!75!black}{This page was intentionally left blank.}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\mbox{}\newpage\fi
    \endgroup\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

And here is the following output:
[image]

What I would like is the top and bottom rules to be of variable length dependent on the length of the chapter's title. Can someone help me with the modifications to be made?

Thanks.

(edit :- changed "width" to "length" as that could lead to confusion)

(edit 2:- added an MWE)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch sure. Give me a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last argument to `\titleformat` can be a command, to which the chapter title is passed as the last argument.

So we can distinguish between numbered and unnumbered chapters. The “Chapter N” bit is only inserted if `\vatsalchapter` has an optional argument.

The whole thing is typeset in a `varwidth`, that is, a minipage that only uses the width of the material inside it. The rules are equally spaced from the title (a visual correction is needed for unnumbered chapters).

If the chapter title is “short”, that is, less than the width of “CHAPTER 10” plus an additional 6pc (that is, 72pt, about one inch), the title is set in a box that wide.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}     
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newlength{\minchapterwidth}
\newlength{\currentchapterwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\minchapterwidth}{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} 10}%
  \addtolength{\minchapterwidth}{6pc}%
}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\itshape\filcenter}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\vatsalchapter[\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~\thechapter]}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\itshape\filcenter}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\vatsalchapter}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vatsalchapter}{om}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \begingroup
  \footnotesize\normalfont
  \IfValueT{#1}{\vatsalrule{1em}\enspace #1\enspace}% numbered chapter
  \vatsalrule{\fill}\par\nointerlineskip
  \IfNoValueT{#1}{\vspace{-0.5\fontcharht\font`A}}%
  \endgroup
  \vspace{1ex}
  \centering
  \settowidth{\currentchapterwidth}{#2}%
  \ifdim\currentchapterwidth<\minchapterwidth
    \makebox[\minchapterwidth]{#2}%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
  \par\nointerlineskip
  \vspace{1ex}
  \vatsalrule{\fill}\par
  \end{varwidth}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vatsalrule}{m}{%
  \leavevmode
  \leaders\hrule height \dimeval{0.5\fontcharht\font`A+0.2pt}
                 depth \dimeval{0.2pt-0.5\fontcharht\font`A}
  \hskip#1\hspace*{0pt}%
}
  
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{36pt}         
\titleformat{\section}
  {\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\S\,\thesection}
  {8pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\Large\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\S\,\thesubsection}
  {8pt}
  {\itshape}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter title}

\section{Section title}

\subsection{Subsection title}

\kant[1]

\chapter{This is a very long chapter title that needs to be split across lines}

\kant[2]

\chapter{Short}

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to ask, how could I go about modifying the above code if I wanted to leave some overhang. Because for extremely short chapter titles it could end up looking ugly. 

I tried modifying the argument of \begin{varwidth} to 1.05\textwidth but it didn't work .

Comment: @VatsalGarg I modified the code to comply. See the last picture.

Comment: It works perfectly now. I wish the author of titlesec adds this example to the next iteration of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (simplified) code.

(1) The length of the longest line of the chapter title is returned in `\titlewidth`. You must use the `calcwidth` package option.

(2) The explicit package option allows using `#1` to make the title explicit.

(3) `block` writes the entire title in a block (a paragraph) without additional formatting. Useful in centered titles.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}     
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, headsep=30pt]{geometry}                 
\usepackage{setspace, parskip}                   
\setstretch{1.25}          

\usepackage[explicit, calcwidth]{titlesec}% changed <<<

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]% % changed <<<
{\filcenter\parbox{\titlewidth}{\rule{.05\linewidth}{0.5pt}%
 \raisebox{-0.6ex}{\footnotesize\, CHAPTER \thechapter\!\enspace}\hrulefill}\\\vspace{1ex}}%
{\Huge\bfseries\itshape\filcenter#1}%
{0pt}{}%
[\vspace{-2ex}\rule{\titlewidth}{0.5pt}]

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip} % changed <<<

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\S\,\thesection\enspace #1}{8pt}{}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip} %added <<<


\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Chapter title}
    \kant[1]
    \section{section title}
    \kant[2-5]
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question.

For unnumbered chapters (like TOC) it is necessary to define a specific format using

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]{ ...
```

The command `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}` will add that chapter to the TOC (optional).

[image: x]

This is the updated code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}     
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, headsep=30pt]{geometry}                 
\usepackage{setspace, parskip}                   
\setstretch{1.25}          

\usepackage[explicit, calcwidth]{titlesec}% changed <<<

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]% % changed <<<
{\filcenter\parbox{\titlewidth}{\rule{.05\linewidth}{0.5pt}%
 \raisebox{-0.6ex}{\footnotesize\, CHAPTER \thechapter\!\enspace}\hrulefill}\\\vspace{1ex}}%
{\Huge\bfseries\itshape\filcenter#1}%
{0pt}{}%
[\vspace{-2ex}\rule{\titlewidth}{0.5pt}]
        
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]% added Unnumbered chapter <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\filcenter\rule{\titlewidth}{0.5pt}\\\vspace{1ex}}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\Huge\bfseries\itshape\filcenter#1}% Add the chapter to the TOC (optional) <<<<
{0pt}{}%
[\vspace{-2ex}\rule{\titlewidth}{0.5pt}]

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip} % changed <<<

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\S\,\thesection\enspace #1}{8pt}{}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip} %added <<<


\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Chapter title}
    \kant[1]
    \section{section title}
    \kant[2-5]
    \chapter*{Unnumbered Chapter title}
    \kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: y]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I like how this modification is simple but it fixes one problem and introduces another. If I use the above code, my unnumbered chapters are broken.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: The modification works after I remove `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}` because all the unnumbered chapters in my document were actually `\chapter` commands in frontmatter and backmatter where the chapter numbers are stripped anyway. 


Thanks for this answer, I wish I could accept both answers.